# How to compare the index of two arrays with each other?

Tags: javascript

i have two array's with each a for each for checking the index.
But now i want to compare the index of both and check if they compare.

These are my array's and for each loops. Can anyone help me with that?

```
 items: ['.js-countdown-item']
 const arrayTime = [days, hours, minutes, seconds]

arrayTime.forEach((item, i) => {
  console.log(i)
})

items.forEach((item, i) => {
  console.log(i)
})
```

Comment: First of all, you need to have arrays with identical lengths so you can loop through one and use the current index (i for example) for both of them.

Comment: Are you going to compare items and arrayTime ?  May be you mean something that possible with lodash. See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual

Comment: why do you want to compare indexes? it makes no sense to me. you could maybe check the length of both arrays to see if they are different

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to demonstrate how to do it :

```
let allIndexesCompare = true;
const check = items.length === arrayTime.length;
// make sure they have the same length
if(check){
   items.forEach((item, i) =>  {
       if(item !== arrayTime[i]) allIndexesCompare = false;
   })
}

// now you have your var "allIndexesCompare" set to true or false, just use it
```

Comment: For long arrays, a plain `for` loop with `break` can save some resources

Comment: yeah true, gotta leave the loop the moment you hit a fail

Answer (score 0):

Array index comparison is of no use. You can simply compare array length for equality otherwise for array value comparison you need the forEach loop

Comment: "you need the forEach loop" - what about plain `for` loop (possible with `break`)? or `reduce`? There are many ways, `forEach` is just one of them (and therefore you do not *need* it)